# React-Bootstrap-Typeahead - how to combine choices

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-typeahead, react-bootstrap-typeahead

When using the mentioned component, we would like to also combine two choices together into a new value. For instance:

1. User types "A"
2. Suggests "Albert" and autocompletes
3. User types "& B"
4. Suggests "Barry"
5. Final value in "Albert & Barry"

So far, we can actually see the suggestions when typing the first part, but obviously when "&" is typed only the "New option" choice is presented.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Concatenating results like that isn't directly supported by the API. Does using the multi-select version not work for your use case? If you absolutely must combine results the way you're describing, you might check out this comment, which is attempting something similar: https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/266#issuecomment-372476843